# Quantum Computing Logo

Tags: discussion, site-design, design

### Question Background

Recently in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43582431#43582431), [Justin Youens](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/52/justin-youens) pointed out that the current logo has little significance to the subject of Quantum Computing.

### The Question

What is the significance of the "square" logo?

### Proposal

Unless the above question has an answer, I think this StackExchange site could benefit from a more relevant logo. Relevant in regards to the field of quantum computation.

### Logo Ideas

If anyone has design ideas to share, please share them.

Comment: I wouldn't go around interpreting it as an atom. I *would* however, go around interpreting it as a Bloch sphere (i.e. possible states of a single qubit), which is more relevant anyway :)

Comment: I like the idea of a bloch sphere being the logo. Maybe not that specific design, as it could be confusing (Is it an eye? Or a bearded, eyeless man wearing a cap?) but something similar could probably work really well.

Comment: Yeah, to be clear it was intended to be an abstract Bloch sphere. We could add more detail, but keep in mind it has to work at a small (favicon, etc) size.

Comment: They made us a logo and have it live on the right column of other sites:  https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/community-promotion-ads-2018/10542#10542 -- I really like @Blue 's suggestion of the Bloch sphere, this is what it looks like with annotations: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1231/278 .

Comment: Please post the logo idea as an answer so that the up/down votes on this thread make sense.

Comment: @DanielSank That is exactly what I intended this thread to be - a suggestion thread for alternative logos. I updated the original post to reflect this idea.

Comment: @DanielBurkhart yes but my point is that the logo in the OP should be in an answer. Meta posts that say *"Let's discuss question Q. Here is my answer A"* are troublesome because answer A cannot be easily voted on in the same way as answers posted by other users.

Comment: @DanielSank I removed the image from my original post and added it as an answer (proposal in the context of this post).

Comment: @DanielBurkhart nice. Thanks!

Comment: what about something along these lines? (pun not intended) https://www.sciencedaily.com/images/2014/07/140714104103_1_540x360.jpg

Comment: After literal years of discussion. What's the next step for changing the logo?

Answer (score 28):

[image: Bloch Sphere Logo as proposed by Justin Youens]

Comment: This logo was created by [Justin Youens](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/52/justin-youens).

Comment: Was it? I thought it was made by the designer from _Strangeworks_. And that Justin is their programmer.

Comment: Could someone create a re-scaled version for community ads?

Comment: See [below](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/198/176) for a modified version of this idea.

Answer (score 19):

Here is an alternative, in Community Ads format. It combines the colors of the existing cube thingammy with a stylized Bloch sphere and ket.

[image]

Sizes &c can be fine-tuned but I think the core idea improves and synthesizes on the existing designs.

The Inkscape source is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0cfwukf5v5e0f75/quantum-computing-2018.svg?dl=0) if people want to tinker with it.

Comment: I like this one: the Bloch sphere and ket are both relevant and match nicely. I also think this idea could even work as favicon: I think it would remain distinguishable enough.

Comment: You probably want to thicken the lines of the ket bracket to make them more visible in a tiny favicon.

Answer (score 11):

Option #4

UPDATE:

Based on the conversation in the comments here are two new versions for review. @emiliopisanty @blue what do you think of these?

Option 4.2

[image: Option 4.2]

Option 4.3

[image: Option 4.3]

Let me know what you think.

***Previous Text***

Ok based in the feedback from [Emilio Pisanty](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/176/emilio-pisanty) we modified the "c" in the original draft to stand upright. Here's the latest version:

[image]

Let me know if there are any additional changes the community would like to see this or any of the other logo drafts and we'll turn them around as fast as possible.

Comment: This is gorgeous. I would suggest turning the inner C so that it's vertical (as in [this one](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/308/176)) while keeping the same Q.

Comment: Thank you Emilio we will make the adjustment this week and post the revised version.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback Emilio, here is the revision based on your feedback. The original idea was to have the "C" revolving around the "Q" to bring a more active sense of superposition, something a little more dynamic than the straight vertical. However, based on your feedback we've created the updated version you see at the top of this post. What do you think about this one?

Comment: @whurley I was thinking more in terms of something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92mJN.png), which is a straight rotation, though now that I see it, it probably needs a designer to work a bit more carefully on the angles on the ends of the C to make it work to its fullest potential. I liked v1 a bit better than the current v2, though.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty checking into it now.

Comment: @Blue that's all up to the community and the mods I'm just trying to help get something clean that the communtiy will like :)

Comment: @Blue I dunno, the inner C's don't look quite as C-y as I imagine they could in the current iterations. I don't know why people are hanging on my opinion, though - I'm just another guy on the internet.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty rofl now you know how I feel :) Hopefully, more people will chime in so we can make sure everyone feels included and the community is involved. Again, it's not like I can make the decision. Just trying to help make sure we have a high quality logo.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hinting at with my lame design, thanks for the effort! I love it and agree with @EmilioPisanty's remarks

Answer (score 3):

[image]

logomakr.com/6KFtQN

Comment: We should high-light _computing_ in our logo, as general quantum questions are off-topic.

Comment: Thank you, I updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

They have a specific format, copying that, your color scheme and adding a Bloch sphere I came up with:

```
 [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2] 
 [1]: http://image-url 
 [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

The SVG came from: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bloch_Sphere.svg#mw-jump-to-license .

No additional text is allowed in the submission, only include what is below this line.

---

[image: Quantum Computing]

Comment: I am not sure, shouldn't the lines be a bit thicker?

Comment: @MEE - Fixed? - I hand edited the SVG and tripled the stroke-width of every line.

Comment: yes, seems to be a lot better

Comment: This one looks busy to me, and not so easy to visually digest. It also focuses rather heavily on the Bloch sphere, which isn't really the essence of quantum computing.

Comment: @DanielSank - You are welcome to make your own submission and upload it as an answer. I am not the "designer" so much as the one whom read the comments to the question and attempted to implement them. The main site has already put forth a proposal of what is thought we would want, if **we** don't come up with something then we get their design.

Comment: @Rob I was simply voicing a comment on this post. I am aware that I can make separate posts. Commenting on this post and making my own are two completely orthogonal things.

Comment: Looks great but wouldn't work in smaller (e.g. favicon) size.

Answer (score 2):

Option #5

[image]

The context for this post is [here](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/304/274)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not too late now to make suggestions for a logo. I agree with the others that the cube is unrelated to our topic. I had the following idea (which a designer could turn into some decent looking logo):

[image: QC logo]

And on a dark background it should look like this:
[image: QC logo dark]

And for the meta:
[image: QC logo meta]

I could provide the svg source if anyone is interested. I think it's neat how it looks like a $\phi$, and of course it's supposed to look like a superposition of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. So it's at least related to what we are doing!

Comment: It is never too late for good ideas. I think the 0/1 in 'superposition' is a bit to complicated for a logo: I'd prefer Emilio Pisanty's Bloch sphere in the ket as a logo. However, when we get to the badges, I think this superposition idea might work: 0 for bronze, 1 for silver, 0/1 for gold.

Answer (score 0):

Here my 2 cents: Inspired in the idea of superimposing symbols, which can be conceptually related to how quantum computing works as user James Wooton already did on [this blog entry](https://medium.com/qiskitters/making-a-quantum-computer-smile-cee86a6fc1de) (not blaming you at all for my lame design!), I came up with the following **concept**:

[image]

It can work as small icon, and can also be mixed up with some other already exposed ideas to make it look more flashy and quantumy if needed. There is [recent discussion](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/208/1346) about the similarity of the current logo to Amazon's AWS. Well, this looks similar to TensorFLow's logo, but I think that choosing different colors could help on that.

Comment: The colors need be more distinct.  As it is now, I almost cannot see anything other than a Q.

Comment: I agree! and also think that the font and other things should definitely be tweaked. I just hope it is visible enough to convey the concept

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to help resolve the [logo debate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43582431#43582431) our own [Justin Youens](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/52/justin-youens) created, the Strangeworks team has looked over the chat, created some original ideas, advanced a few ideas from above (shout our to [fr-andres](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1346/fr-andres) superimposing symbols) and would like to submit the following as some possible candidates for the new community logo.

*NOTE: We've kept them all colorless so decisions can be made on the design alone. Once the community pics one (or gives us the feedback to do revisions, start over, etc) we can do a color exploration and provide some color options.*

I'm posting each option is being posted as a separate answer so people can upvote their favorite. Starting with option one being included in this post:

[image]

Comment: You know, I really like them in grayscale...

Answer (score 0):

Option #2

[image]

The context for this post is [here](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/304/274)

Answer (score 0):

Option #3

[image]

The context for this post is [here](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/304/274)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Source:** https://www.research.ibm.com/ibm-q/learn/what-is-quantum-computing/

Answer (score -3):

There is a question in another answer about how it would look scaled to favicon size (32x32).

This is about as good it gets using a cellphone and the available tools.

[image: Original 320x320 Source Image]

That's the original source image from which the smaller size was derived.

[image: Reduced Image - 32x32]

That's the result of reducing it to 32x32 using a smart resizing algorithm (not *simple* scaling).

[image: The Bloch sphere overlaid]

That's what it looks like with the Bloch sphere overlaid, lots of detail lost.

[image: Converted to B&W]

Converted to B&W, so it can be overlaid on to the greenish background.

The rules for submitting a design made no mention of developing a version for the icons used on the site, perhaps someone intends to take what is submitted and hand it over to a professional Graphics Designer (to preserve the Stack Exchange *image* and avoid sketchy looking sketches, along with providing some uniformity to the look).

If other people create a design there will likely be a better result and certainly more for people to vote on. That's what a sphere would look like, don't know what a cube had to do with QC; now we have both.