# Does anyone else feel that the logo for this stack is too similar to Amazon Web Services' favicon?

Tags: discussion

Here is a side by side comparison of the favicon for this site and for amazon web services:

[image]

And here they are again, in a screen shot of my browser tabs:

[image]

When this logo started showing up in the Hot Network Questions, I had assumed that there was a new AWS stack that started up, but was (pleasantly) surprised to see that it was about quantum computing.

I don't have any suggestions at the moment, but it might be better to move to something a little more different from such a major brand.

---

related thread: [Quantum Computing Logo](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/quantum-computing-logo)

Comment: I can see the similarities, but [they're not quite the same](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/AmazonWebservices_Logo.svg)

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Right, AWS has a logo that's pretty different, but their favicon is nearly identical. I think it's the one on the right in the image in my question.