# Updated theme with Left Navigation is live for Quantum Computing

Tags: discussion, design

You may have noticed that your site theme changed!

As part of implementing the new unified themes across the network, we're [gradually rolling out updated site themes for each site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314979/rollout-of-responsive-design-site-themes-tracking-post). As of today, we have enabled your updated site theme. Since your site design was done relatively recently and it's not changing much outside of the left navigation, we've pushed it out live from the start, rather than in a testing mode the way we have on other recent site design releases.

Please note, there may likely be some bugs in this design, so please use this post to let us know about them! This isn't 100% final, so feel free to let us know if there are elements we can improve on. We're aware that you're interested in a [new logo](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/quantum-computing-logo) and that's on our list of future improvements already but it will still be a bit before we can get to it.

### What type of feedback do we need?

#### On this post: Bugs related to this site's design elements

Please help us look for issues/bugs related to the theme design and how we have mapped the old theme to the new. This needs to be done within the [limits of the new unified theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes).

#### On Meta Stack Exchange: General concerns about left nav or theming

If you have concerns or issues regarding the left nav or the overall approach we are taking to theming, then [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) is the right place for feedback.

There may be some unique design elements like voting arrows and tags that are being standardized in this process. Keeping these custom elements makes our ability to maintain the sites too complex and, while we're very sad to see them go, we're in a difficult position of needing to make the site designs work together so that we can continue to address feature requests and bugs that will make your Q&A experience better. This is addressed in a [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) if you want more detail.

### What new themes?

If you're like, "What the heck are you talking about?", then you should read the Meta Stack Exchange post entitled [Rollout of new network site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312365/rollout-of-new-network-site-themes) (and maybe the posts it links to for the full background). To follow along with the rollout of these new themes, go here.

### Thanks so much for your constructive feedback!

Comment: Personally I feel the left nav takes away far too much space (at least on my 12" laptop), but since it can be disabled that's not an issue.  Hope the possibility to disable it stays!

Comment: Being able to move the left nav to the hamburger menu should stick around, @NorbertSchuch :)