# Do we want to change the logo of this site?

Tags: discussion, site-design

I recently noticed the [logo of Amazon AWS](https://signin.aws.amazon.com/) and [quantum computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) was almost identical. I'm far from competent in law but are there legal implications? Since we are [considering revising](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/do-we-want-to-change-the-name-of-this-site) the site name, in light of this (and maybe anything else) do we want to change the logo for quantum computing as well?

Comment: we discussed it some time ago, but then just sort of never went through with it, see [Quantum Computing Logo](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/89/55). Regardless of the site name matter, it will probably be good to also take a final decision on this as well, yes. I doubt there's any legal issue with the current one though, or SE wouldn't have used it (but of course, IANAL)

Comment: @glS how would we go about making this decision? Personally, I feel that changing the logo to better reflect the theme of the website is a good idea, but, what is the criteria to determine the community agrees with this? After this is decided, would there be some sort of voting system for the new logo?

Comment: @epelaaez good question. Generally speaking, yes, decisions are taken trying to assess "community consensus" via "poll meta posts", like we're doing now. I added an answer proposing a way to proceed on this regard.

Answer (score 4):

I *strongly* doubt there is any "legal implication" to be worried about, as otherwise we wouldn't have the current logo in the first place (which was chosen/approved by Strangeworks/StackExchange).

Regarding changing it, a number of ideas were proposed before a few years ago [in this post](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/89/55). For no particular reason I'm aware of, we never went through with it, so yes, I agree this would be a good chance to revive the matter.

My proposal on how to proceed is:

1. Let's settle the site-name-change matter.
2. Make a meta post presenting the various options already given in the previous posts, to allow people to vote on them. I think it might be useful to do another round of voting to avoid skewed results due to some proposals being brought up before others. Maybe add a "keep current logo" option in this post to make sure enough people want a change in the first place.
3. Make a final meta post of the form "Do we change the logo to X", where X is the most upvoted option in the previous post. Deal with the case in which multiple options have roughly the same number of net upvotes if it happens.

Of course, I'm open to alternative ideas on how to proceed with this.