# Custom badge icon

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-design

Like how AcademiaSE,

[image]

and ChemistrySE,

[image]

have custom badge icons; it would be cool if we also have something like that. Something like an electron spin

[image]

Or one of the submissions for the initial QCSE site icon.

[image]

I am not sure if StackExchange has a policy on which communities can have custom badge icons.

Answer (score 2):

## I like your idea

I think your first suggestion would be appropriate:

[image].

## A bit about site designs on SE

Custom badge logos fall under "site design", which for ***unsponsored*** sites, is not likely to happen for a site of our size a few more years. The table below may convince you of the reason for this (questions/day is a 14-day average):

| Site still without a "complete" design | Age | Total questions | Questions/day on 1/11/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Engineering | 8 years 10 months | 16k | 6.4 |
| Law | 8 years 6 months | 28k | 16 |
| Quantum Computing | 5 years 8 months | 10k | 6.2 |

Quantum computing is a "sponsored" site though, meaning that it got a head start with its site design, but this may have been done in a rush by  Strangeworks so that William Hurley could advertise the site at the SXSW conference (see [Why does the Quantum Computing site look different?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/2293)). The other site that got a head start with their site design due to "sponsorship" was AI.SE and they also don't have custom badge logos.

Interestingly, [Data Science SE recently got its design done  in August 2022](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/91311) but with no badge logos, and [same with Islam.SE](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3576/11743), and [same with Arduino.SE](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2716/49944) and [same with Mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2113/44515) and same with [German.SE](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1697/33642) and [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5314/33564) and [French.SE](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/24888) and [Spanish.SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4448/26133) in September 2022. To make things even more confusing, [Chess.SE ***did*** get custom badge logos in April 2023](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1121/23006), but [Writing.SE did not](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2492/44466) and [Gardening.SE did not](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/961/28289).  Also strange is that [Etherium.SE got custom badges with their site design in July 2022](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/697/46119) but [Bitcoin.SE did not in September 2022](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1109/90058). [Quantitative Finance SE](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1684/36393) got a custom badge logo in March 2023 and [Sound Design SE](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1477/30413) got one in December 2022.

I now doubt that our sponsorship means enough to SE for them to prioritize giving us a custom badge logo. **If you want to shed light on the path towards getting a custom badge logo, I suggest to find out why all of the above-linked sites that did not get custom badge logos despite being older than QCSE (and in all cases except for Spanish.SE, also are more rich in terms of the total number of questions) did not get custom badge logos, or why Etherium.SE and Chess.SE did get custom badge logos, despite Chess.SE having fewer total questions than QCSE right now**

## More related information

- [Quantum Computing Logo](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/89/2293)
- [Do we want to change the logo of this site?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/493/2293)
- [Why does the Quantum Computing site look different?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/2293)
- [Comments on Physics.SE.Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10542/134583)
- [A similar announcement on Artificial Intelligene SE](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1404/19524)
- [Meta.SE announcement about sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307861/391772)
- [Meta.SE announcement about site design statuses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326798/391772)
- [Meta.SE status updates for all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363/391772)

## SE's stance

In [this Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/391772) we see that custom badge logos are "possible but not promised":

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer regarding this.